WixToolset DotNetCompatibilityCheck - How to use RollForward?
Disclaimer: This code is not a fully functional snippet, yes I am aware of, anyhow I think the question is obvious enough.
I am using netfx extension of the Wix Toolset project.
    <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck
            Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK_8_0_0"
            RollForward="major"
            RuntimeType="desktop"
            Platform="x64"
            Version="8.0.0" />

On the documentation of the Wix Toolset (MSI / EXE Installer Tool) dotnetcompatibilitycheck - RollForward
I found this:

RollForward (enumeration) :
The roll forward policy to use while validating. This attribute's value must be one of the following:

latestMajor
major
latestMinor
minor
latestPatch
disable


And also I found that link Wix Toolset - Detecting and installing .NET.
But on both a details info about RollForward is missing.
What does each value mean? When I should use major when minor or the other values?
Here more examples of smaller version changes
    <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck
            Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK_8_0_0"
            RollForward="major"
            RuntimeType="desktop"
            Platform="x64"
            Version="8.0.0" />
    <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck
            Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK_8_0_9"
            RollForward="major"
            RuntimeType="desktop"
            Platform="x64"
            Version="8.0.9" />
      <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck
            Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK_8_0_10"
            RollForward="major"
            RuntimeType="desktop"
            Platform="x64"
            Version="8.0.10" />
    <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck
            Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK_8_0_11"
            RollForward="major"
            RuntimeType="desktop"
            Platform="x64"
            Version="8.0.11" />

I have installed Microsoft .NET SDK 8.0.403 (x86) which contains .NET Runtime v8.0.11.
So the DotNetCompatibilityChecks above will be validated to

true
true
true
false

So I am still confused about RollForward behavior

On the MS Learn - dotnet docu for global.json I found a bit more details.
